# Static file in MonoRail can not be loaded in Forms Authentication mode

Tags: forms-authentication, castle-monorail

I applied Forms authentication to my monorail project.

In login page, all static files can not be loaded. It seems that the static file can be loaded only after user logged in. In login page, the request to script.js is redirected to

http://localhost:49529/MySite/Login/Index.rails?ReturnUrl=%2fMySite2fContent%2fjs%2fscripts.js

Thanks for any help.

Comment: static files should not go through Monorail (or ASP.NET for that matter) but directly to the StaticFilesHandler or whatever it's called.

Comment: you'd need to share a couple of more details to get a proper help here:
1. which IIS are you using
2. how does your web.config file looks

Comment: I think you have applied authentication for all paths on the website in your web.config, that won't fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go extension less path and register "*" request to go through MonoRail this might be the case.

Try to add StaticFileHandler before MonorailHttpHandlerFactory setting like this:

```
<add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"/>
<add verb="*" path="*.zip" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"/>
...
<add verb="*" path="*" 
  type="Castle.MonoRail.Framework.MonoRailHttpHandlerFactory,
    Castle.MonoRail.Framework"/>
```